# Is it possible to update one attribute belonging to multiple children within one parent tag on visual studio code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Say you have a situation where you have 30-40 options and you want to change the name="" attribute from blank to something suitable. Is there a way you can do this in one instance using visual studio code? I think it would be a great feature. There is a similar function for updating a tag.

```
<div>
  <p>
    What aspects of service are you looking for when deciding on your utility providers?
    <span class="clue">(Check all that apply)</span>
  </p>

  <label
    ><input
      name=""
      value="customer-care"
      type="checkbox"
      class="input-checkbox"
    />Customer Care</label
  >
  <label>
    <input
      name=""
      value="affordable-service"
      type="checkbox"
      class="input-checkbox"
    />Affordable Service</label
  >
</div>
```

The duplicate code options are good to know and is certainly fine for the situation I'm presenting, but say we have names and decide we aren't happy with them? I still think this question might be worth asking in case there is a way you can edit single attributes within a parent without deleting everything.

Thanks for your help

Comment: what do you want the `name` attribute to be

Comment: if I just wanted to call it name="trial", but I didn't want to write it in 40 times..

Comment: naming 40 objects `trial` will not help you a lot, you can use [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen) to generate numbered text for the multi cursors you have: `trial{{=i+1}}`

Comment: Thanks for your observation. This is just an example. I have noticed the VS code is able to recognise and highlight words as you highlight them. I don't think it would be out of this world to expect an extension has been made to allow you to modify all words that are the same as the one you have selected within a few parameters. I.e only affect attributes, classes, id's or children tags within a parent element. I think it could be quite useful. If the regex text generator does that then thanks very much. If it doesn't also thank you very much for the tip!

Comment: you can select with emmet the whole content of a tag, then with regex find you can search in selection, and place multi cursors on all locations and then edit every location at the same time, and then you can use the Regex Text Generator to create different texts with sequence numbers or part of the find selected texts

Comment: Did you design it? ;)

Comment: `Regex Text Generator` is one of the VSC extensions I have written

Answer (score 0):

I found the tool I was looking for and it didn't require an extension.

There is a function in Visual studio code that comes out of the box (I believe or may be linked to Emmet). This allows you to find and replace a string of linking characters. It's very useful if you wish to edit multiple attributes of the same value.

Highlight the text you wish to modify.
click 'ctrl + f' to find all instances of the string.
Click the arrow to the left of the text area (or press 'shift + tab' then enter)
Press tab twice to get to the replace text area, write your new text
Finally press 'ctrl + alt + enter' to replace all instances of your highlighted string.

Just posting this in case any newbies like myself find it hard to get the replace tool going.